# jQuery autocomplete multiple minLength

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if a numeric value is coming from the "#lookup" field,
if it is numeric I need to set up the minLength to 5, else it will minLength: 3,

Is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#lookup" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "script.pl",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(response){
                    alert('Somethings broken in the AJAX return');
                }
            });
        },
        close:function(){
            this.value=''
        },
        // need to check here if a numeric value is coming from #lookup
        // if it is, I would like to set this to: minLength: 5,
        // else minLength: 3,
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 500
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should check whether or not a value, even if it is a string initially, converts to a numeric value safely:

```
function isNumeric(n) { 
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n); 
}
```

found here: http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/javascript-isnumeric/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
$("#lookup").on('keyup', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(isNumeric($this.val())) {
        $this.data('uiAutocomplete').options.minLength = 5
    }
})
```

and the isNumetic function from @Dpeif answer:

```
function isNumeric(n) { 
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n); 
}
```

Comment: You need to add it into the `$(document).ready` after you call `autocomplete` on '$("#lookup")'. You can add `isNumeric` function globally if you want.